# Arrange column values in one line using R

Tags: r, output, line

I have a df like below.

```
df:

Year   max_T  min_T   Prcp 
1990   25.00  2.50    525.25 
1991   30.00  1.50   1001.25
.
.
2010   22.25  5.25   1025.25
```

I need to obtain or convert the above data table the following output.

```
output:

1990 25.00 2.50 525.25, 1991 30.00  1.50  1001.25,..., 2010 22.25  5.25  1025.25
```

I need to have an output in one line (NOTE: Years should separate by comma and values should separate by tab). I do not need the column names in the output.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `paste` in `R`

```
toString(do.call(paste, df))
```

Or with a single call

```
do.call(paste, c(df, list(collapse=", ")))
#[1] "1990 25 2.5 525.25, 1991 30 1.5 1001.25"
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Year = 1990:1991, max_T = c(25, 30), min_T = c(2.5, 
 1.5), Prcp = c(525.25, 1001.25)), .Names = c("Year", "max_T", 
 "min_T", "Prcp"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L
 ))
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked and can you explain what the do.call function and collapse does here.? Thanks again.

Comment: @DinuJ When you do `paste` within `do.call`, it will paste the `list` elements to a single string

Answer (score 0):

`DataFrame` has `to_string` to deal with that.

```
import re
import pandas as pds

reg = re.compile(r'[ ]+')

df = pds.DataFrame([[1990, 25, 2.50, 525.25], [1991, 30.00, 1.50, 1001.25]])
rows = df.to_string(header=False, index=False, index_names=False).split('\n')
print(rows)
rows = [reg.sub('\t', r) for r in rows]
s = ', '.join(rows)

print(s)

# 1990  25.0    2.5 525.25, 1991    30.0    1.5 1001.25
```

Comment: I want to do this in R not in python

Comment: @DinuJ Sorry missed that! But maybe the same logic

Comment: I am new to R language.